# User spamming posts with advertisement comments

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, flagging

A user is advertising by spamming comments in webapps section, I've flagged his most of the comments out there, but no actions are being taken by moderators, why?

Comment: Please don't call out users by name in public posts. Flagging was the appropriate action; moderators on all the Stack Exchange site take a dim view of spammers and crush their "contributions" as soon as possible. As [phwd pointed out](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/970/user-spamming-posts-with-advertisement-comments/971#971) moderators are volunteers and can't always be online.

Comment: @AlEverett Ok bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been logged now and the user has been suspended. We try to be online 24/7 but sometimes things slip through. This was an edge case where no one was online during the hours this issue took place. Thanks for bringing it up.